# Custom File comparator in Groovy giving GroovyCastException

Tags: sorting, groovy

I am trying to do a custom file sort with Groovy in a Jenkins environment. Even before putting in any special condition, I get an exception.

```
File applicationsFolder = new File(GENERATION_FOLDER, "apks");
File[] applications = applicationsFolder.listFiles().sort({ lhs, rhs ->
    lhs.compareTo(rhs)
});
```

Gives me the following :

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '7' with class 'java.lang.Integer' to class 'java.io.File'
```

Is the syntax correct? I don't see where any integer is implied in what I've written above...
Thanks!

**Edit:** Note that `applicationsFolder.listFiles()` does indeed return a list of 5 File objects representing folders (the listed folder contains only subfolders). Note also that `applicationsFolder.listFiles().sort()` alone returns the expected result. Things get complicated only with the Comparator...

Comment: I ran the same code, prepending with ```File applicationsFolder = new File("/tmp")```, and everything worked swimmingly, including sorting. Could you maybe show us how you set up the variable ```applicationsFolder```?

Comment: Hi, thanks for running it for me. Knowing it succeeds on your side confirms I'm not crazy thinking this code should work! ;) I've added a few more details to the question.

Comment: Can you try calling `listFile().iterator().sort { .. }` instead?

Comment: Unfortunately, same result.

Comment: Well, the integer must be coming from the `compareTo` call. You're doing it correctly according to the GroovyDocs. Out of curiosity, what if you were to coerce the Closure into a comparator?  `{ lhs, rhs -> lhs.compareTo(rhs) } as Comparator`

Comment: Good idea. Unfortunately, I get the same result. The integer '7' is indeed a comparison result : I changed the folders name and got the same error with integer '-1'. So somehow it tries to cast the comparison result (integer) into a file in the process...

Comment: Do you have any idea what version of Groovy is running in your Jenkins environment?

Comment: In the Jenkins' About I have `Apache Groovy org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.7` and `Stapler Groovy module org.kohsuke.stapler:stapler-groovy:1.243`. Unfortunately, `println GroovySystem.version` is denied at runtime.